# mySQL - populating the tables in EER diagram and generating .sql file

Tags: mysql, schema

I'm newer to mySQL and I'm having some difficulty generating a .sql file with insert statements:
I have made an EER diagram, forward engineered this diagram to generate the database, then used the insert statement in the terminal to insert values into my tables.
Now I'm having difficulty bringing this new/updated database back to mySQL workbench and create a .sql file of the whole thing (schema+ what was inserted into the tables).
I had no luck looking here or searching videos on uTube. Any help/links is highly appreciated to show the step by step walk through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have [logged into MySQL workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html) then tried going to the schema tab (on the left) and hitting the two arrows that make a circle -- that should populate any tables that you've inserted into terminal. if not you can manually add the script file using one of the button on the top left "open a SQL script file". Check out this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S_tz1z_5bA&t=1424s) for more info.

Comment: Thanks the tip about refreshing the database in MySQL workbench was helpful, and I figured out how to generate the .sql file of my database by exporting.